# Why won't my menu bar pop up with my display window?

Tags: java, swing, menu

I'm trying to write up a little "game" that consists of a U.F.O. that flies in all directions (based on buttons) and explodes when it hits the bottom of the screen. I have 4 classes, 2 of which I'm not allowed to edit. They are:

The display window

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public  class DisplayWindow extends JFrame{

  private Container c;

  public DisplayWindow(){
    super("Display");
    c = this.getContentPane();
  }

  public void addPanel(JPanel p){
    c.add(p);
  }

  public void showFrame(){
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

And the driver for the UFO.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SaucerDriver{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    DisplayWindow d = new DisplayWindow();
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    d.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    SaucerPanel p = new SaucerPanel(menuBar);
    d.addPanel(p);
    d.showFrame();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add a menu bar but it wont show up. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my class for drawing all the buildings and whatnot

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class SaucerPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
  JButton quitButton;
  JButton upButton;
  JButton leftButton;
  JButton rightButton;
  JButton downButton;  
  int xLoc;
  int yLoc;
  boolean explode;

  public SaucerPanel(JMenuBar menuBar){
    xLoc = 20;
    yLoc = 200;

    explode = false;

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850,500));
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
    this.add(quitButton);
    quitButton.addActionListener(this);

    downButton = new JButton("Down");
    this.add(downButton);
    downButton.addActionListener(this);

    upButton = new JButton("Up");
    this.add(upButton);
    upButton.addActionListener(this);

    leftButton = new JButton("Left");
    this.add(leftButton);
    leftButton.addActionListener(this);

    rightButton = new JButton("Right");
    this.add(rightButton);
    rightButton.addActionListener(this);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(0,440,850,60);

    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(80,420,210,100);
      g.fillRect(100,410,170,100);
      g.fillRect(120,400,130,100);
      g.fillOval(130,350,110,150);
      int[] aPoints = {170,200,185};
      int[] bPoints = {370,370,320};
        g.fillPolygon(aPoints,bPoints, 3);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillRect(135,410,20,100);
       g.fillRect(175,410,20,100);
       g.fillRect(215,410,20,100);

      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.fillRect(460,140,120,360);

      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.fillRect(700,400,100,150);

      g.setColor(Color.yellow);
      int[] xPoints = {700,800,750};
      int[] yPoints = {400,400,350};
      g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);

      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillRect(730,450,40,50);

      g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
    if(explode == false){
      g.fillOval(xLoc,yLoc,80,40);
      g.drawString("hovering...",xLoc,yLoc - 10);
    }else{
      for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
        int x = (int)(Math.random()*850);
        int y = (int)(Math.random()*850);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillOval(x,y,5,5);
        int a = (int)(Math.random()*850);
        int b = (int)(Math.random()*850);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(a,b,5,5);
        int c = (int)(Math.random()*850);
        int d = (int)(Math.random()*850);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(c,d,5,5);
      }
    }
  }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == quitButton){
          System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == downButton){
          yLoc += 5;
          if(yLoc == 400){
            explode = true;
          }
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == upButton){
          yLoc -= 5;
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == leftButton){
          xLoc -= 5;
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == rightButton){
          xLoc += 5;
        }

        repaint();
      }
    }
```

And here is my menu bar class

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class menuBar extends JFrame{

  public menuBar(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(850,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(file);
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    file.add(open);
    JMenuItem neww = new JMenuItem("New");
    file.add(neww);

    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(edit);
    JMenuItem color = new JMenuItem("Change Color");
    edit.add(color);

    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(help);
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    help.add(about);

    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you have two JFrame classes? Surely you just want to add your JMenuBar to the DisplayWindow class?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want to do, but I can only edit the Menu class and the SaucerPanel class. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a few small changes.

- Your MenuBar class should not extend JFrame, it should extend JMenuBar.
- Your SaucerDriver class needs to add YOUR MenuBar class and not create a new JMenuBar, as it is empty, and is not populated anywhere in your code.

Your code should look like this

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class menuBar extends JMenuBar{

  public menuBar(){

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    this.add(file);
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    file.add(open);
    JMenuItem neww = new JMenuItem("New");
    file.add(neww);

    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    this.add(edit);
    JMenuItem color = new JMenuItem("Change Color");
    edit.add(color);

    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    this.add(help);
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    help.add(about);
  }
}
```

and SaucerDriver like this

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SaucerDriver{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    DisplayWindow d = new DisplayWindow();
    d.setJMenuBar(new menuBar());
    SaucerPanel p = new SaucerPanel(menuBar);
    d.addPanel(p);
    d.showFrame();
  }
}
```

EDIT: as you cannot change the SauceDriver AND a JMenuBar object is passed into the SaucerPanel object, then you can manipulate the MenuBar from the SaucerPanel class. Therefore, do the following...

```
public SaucerPanel(JMenuBar menuBar){
    setMenuBarItems(menuBar);
    //...rest of the JPANEL code here
}
```

and add this method to your SaucerPanel class

```
public void setMenuBarItems(JMenuBar menuBar) {
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(file);
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    file.add(open);
    JMenuItem neww = new JMenuItem("New");
    file.add(neww);

    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(edit);
    JMenuItem color = new JMenuItem("Change Color");
    edit.add(color);

    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(help);
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    help.add(about);
}
```

Comment: I cant edit the SaucerDriver or the DisplayWindow class. They were given to me.

Comment: Then you have two options. Firstly, you can create your own Main class, in place of SaucerDriver, and add the JMenuBar....or, from the SaucerPanel class, you can getParent of the JPanel (which will be the JFrame), and add set the menubar there.

Comment: I'll do the second one since I have to use his main class but I'm not really sure what .getParent is..

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent() It is inherited from Container, which JPanel extends. It gives you the parent item, so as you have added a JPanel to the frame, calling getParent on the JPanel will give you the Frame.

Comment: see my edit. for the best solution of how to solve this in your case. Passing the JMenuBar into the JPanel is bad practice, but I am assuming your professor did it so that you did not need to change the code for the 2 classes provided.